# Will my Xbox 360 from the UK work when I move to Australia?

Tags: region-lock, xbox-360

I own (and love) an Xbox 360 and nearly 50 games which I play regularly and I have a Live gold membership.
I will soon be emigrating to Australia and was wondering will I be able to take my 360 and use it like here...

1. Will it work with TVs/broadband etc. over there?
2. Will I be able to retain my LIVE account?
3. What are the prices/availability of games/accessories like compared to the UK? i.e. Is it worth me stocking up on games before I go because they are more expensive there?
4. Perhaps as I'm moving to country with a fantastic climate (compared to here!) I should consider getting out more and playing less games? ;)
5. (**EDIT**: Added to match accepted answer below!) Will games bought in Australia work on my UK Xbox system?

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. - **Yes,** they should work with your TV, as both the UK and the AUS region use the [PAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL) system, however, be aware that you might need to buy new power cords over there.
   - As proper broadband uses [CAT5 Cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) worldwide, a normal plug & play broadband connection should always work. (also, wireless also uses the same basic system worldwide, so no problems there too.)
2. I sadly wasn't able to find a conclusive answer for this question, however, my tentative guess would be that it is possible.
3. - As far as I know, (and a [Google Search](http://www.google.nl/search?q=australian+game+prices) seems to agree) prices of games in Australia are more expensive, and with the low £, it might be profitable to stocking up games. (your best bet is to do some price comparison on the games you think on stocking up.)
   - Be aware however, if you think about trading-in games in Australia that this can be slightly difficult for UK games dependant on Game and Retailer. (luckily no language barrier, just ratings)
   - Also, be aware of the [Australian Censor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_in_Australia#Video_games) when Importing [Certain Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_banned_video_games#Australia)
4. Do what you like the best, weither it is gaming or enjoying the climate, just don't overdo it.
5. **(BONUS)** Games bought Down Under should usually also work on your system, as both Europe and Australia are usually considered to be in the same zone (related to point 1)

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks for your help particularly on (1) and (3)

Answer (score 6):

Regarding point 2:

Your account will work, but you will need to use a UK credit card to buy points and games on demand. There is no way to switch your account to Australia, it will remain a UK account.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will be able to retain your Live account, however, you will have to buy UK Microsoft points cards in order to stock up your account, or retain a UK credit card. Microsoft will not allow you to change the nationality, even when they are at fault (as I found out).

Comment: Yeah, I got burned by the point card incompatibility too (going from US to UK).

Answer (score 1):

A simple travel adaptor from UK to Australia should work - 
Australia is 230V +- 6 to 10%, 50Hz AC
UK is rated at 230V +- 6%, 50Hz AC

Very little difference. And don't worry about getting out. In summer (depending on the city you live in) you can have blackouts because everyone turns on their air conditioner. That's your cue to get out and do sociable things.

EDIT: Alexanderpas is right. Games are ridiculously overpriced here. I'm considering buying from the UK nowadays - even with shipping it's cheaper (EG. Call of Duty black ops is about $80 AUD or approx. £51.38 GBP[on 15/11/2011]. By comparison on Amazon it is £25.