# I'm moving to another country. Should I take my Xbox 360 or buy a new one there?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm about to move to UK from Poland and would like to know if it's better to buy a new one over there or take mine with me.

Main aspects:

- UK have different power sockets, but adapters are available
- Voltage is 230V in both countries
- What about my Xbox Live account? It's registered for Poland.
- Is there anything more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the answers to my question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/will-my-xbox-360-from-the-uk-work-when-i-move-to-australia) might be of interest - although I have moved from UK to Australia

Comment: This is an indirect answer, but helps a lot - Thank You!