# Can I play UK games on a French Xbox 360 or vice versa?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

I have just bought an French Xbox 360 from a French friend with 30 French games. Can I use this console back in the UK on Xbox Live? Can I use the games on an English console? What will my limitations be?

Comment: I've once asked the same question to a guy working in a store specialized in video games. He told me something about PAL (Europe) games running fine on a PAL console, but if you try to play NTSC (US) games on a PAL console, the graphics will be monochrome. I'm not sure about the "monochrome" part, but I did play a French Xbox 360 game on a non-French PAL Xbox 360. Only downside might be the audio language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will my Xbox 360 from the UK work when I move to Australia?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/will-my-xbox-360-from-the-uk-work-when-i-move-to-australia)

Answer (score 2):

Judging from [this page](http://www.play-asia.com/paOS-00-3-xbox360_compatibility_guide-49-en.html) I found during my quick search, it seems what regions a 360 game is compatible with vary depending on the game. However, the UK and France are both considered to be in the PAL territory. Worst case scenario is you may be unable to play certain games against English-speaking people on Xbox Live, however I'm not sure.